# Connection / Tunnel to AWS RDS from EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm working on a website hosted in a VPC on AWS. Yesterday, we moved the mysql server from a EC2 instance to a RDS instance to allow the mysql server to perform better. So, before, when I wanted to restart the database server I could connect trough ssh to the EC2 instance and execute the following linux command:

```
service mysql restart
```

As I can see, the RDS instance is prepared to serve mysql but not to execute linux commands. Am I right? Does it mean that I have to restart the hole instance to restart the mysql server?

Thank you!

Comment: *to allow the mysql server to perform better* ?

Comment: @Anatoly Presumably moving it off of the application server to it's own instance.

Comment: Why is restarting MySQL a common occurrence for you?

Comment: @Anatoly yes, as EEAA comments, the web server and the database server were both running at the same EC2 instance, and now, the database has its own intance.

Comment: @ceejayoz I hope no to need any more it but we have had issues with innodb_buffer_pool and from time to time, mysql server stoped working so it needed to be restarted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As I can see, the RDS instance is prepared to serve mysql but not to
>   execute linux commands. Am I right?

Yes, that is correct. It is indeed running on a linux OS, but you as an RDS user do not get access to OS-level commands.

> Does it mean that I have to restart the hole instance to restart the
>   mysql server?

Correct. I guess my question would be: why are you needing to restart MySQL? In general, there should be no reason to restart more often than a couple times during development while you are tweaking mysql settings.

Comment: the point is that we have had some problems because the innodb_buffer_pool could not allocate memory what made mysql server stop working.

Comment: Now, the RDS monitoring reveals that our instance consumes 3.5Gb, of 4Gb RAM. It seems that the database consumes too RAM and I'm afraid it could stop mysql again :S The whole app is a wordpress-woocommerce app. Actions to be take are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: That is a separate question, go ahead and post it as such.